# Sphere inside cylinder vs polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, polyhedra

- Comparing a cylinder with a polyhedra that has a symmetric coxeter $\ge 3$.
- Both have their centers hollowed out by $k\%$, in the shape of their outer, i.e.: relative to top face

#### Which can better hold a sphere?

Note: the sphere's diameter is equal to the the hollowed out diameter.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of "can better hold a sphere"?

Comment: This is for materials engineering, but I'm trying to figure out the maths (or physics?) behind it. By 'better hold' I mean 'better grip'. So more force would be required to dislodge with {polyhedra|cylinder} based on theorem <>. Hmm, thinking about it now, maybe it's a physics.stackexchange question?